# How to map id to _id when serializing/deserializing doc in MongoDB using Jackson?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongo-jackson-mapper

I am looking for a way to map _id to id of the doc which I serialize or desrialize from Mongo DB. I am using Jackson for my project. Here is what my id fields looks like.

```
@Valid 
@ObjectId
//not sure what to write here; @JsonProperty(value="_id") gives error 
@JsonProperty(value="id") 
public String id;
```

The document which I save in Mongo has entry for both id and _id

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5441902d0364200c32dde326"), 
  "id" : ObjectId("544178130364350e7bad171b")
}
```

Is there a way I can map "id" to "_id" for serializing and vice versa when deserializing? The reason I need this mapping is because we have used "id" everywhere (lot of places) on client side.

Related Link: [Rename ObjectId _id to id in jackson deserialization with Jongo and MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25512381/rename-objectid-id-to-id-in-jackson-deserialization-with-jongo-and-mongodb)

Comment: Have you tried using JAXB annotations?

Comment: Also, as far as I know, it has to read `@ObjectId @Id String id;` plus whatever annotation you want/need. `@Id` is not implicit.