# Play 2.3 Jongo ObjectId to custom ID

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, jackson, jongo

I use Play 2.3 scala with play-jongo:

`"uk.co.panaxiom" %% "play-jongo" % "0.7.1-jongo1.0"`

I have scala case class:

```
import org.jongo.marshall.jackson.oid.Id
case class User(@Id id: String, name: String)
```

When i save some user using Jongo `PlayJongo.getCollection("users").save(User("uuid","user name"))`

I have following in my DB:

```
{ 
    "_id" : { "$oid" : "5612a4effa93746a877c0d5c"} , 
    "id" : "uuid", 
    "name": "user name"
}
```

When required result would be with string valued `_id` which maps to `id` attribute in scala class:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "uuid", 
    "name": "user name"
}
```

Everything works OK when i turn my scala case class to Java POJO (simple example below). In this case i get required result.

```
public class User {
    @Id
    public String id;
    public String name;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I make jackson/jongo understand that `@Id` annotation correctly?

In [other SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25512381/rename-objectid-id-to-id-in-jackson-deserialization-with-jongo-and-mongodb) there are suggestions to use `@Id` annotation - which I use - without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the RTFM rule pays off after all. It's stated at [play-jongo readme](https://github.com/alexanderjarvis/play-jongo#jongo-mapper) that it's enough to add `Jackson Module Scala` dependency to the project and configure mapper.

Add dependency to `build.sbt`:

```
"com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.6.1",
```

Configure mapper in `application.conf`

```
playjongo.mapperfactory="uk.co.panaxiom.playjongo.JongoScalaMapperFactory"
```